# Android gridview, how to remove the gaps between grid items

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I am trying to use GridView to achieve a mosaic effect. The grid items are all images, similar to the Gri 2 in the APIDemo sample. The problem is that there are always gaps between the images, even after all the padding and spacing are set to 0. Did I miss some other settings to remove the gap? I want the images right next to each other.

I set the column width as 120dip. Here is my code to set the image width to 120dip:

```
mTileWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 120, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Is there a problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the methods mentioned in the answers but they do not work. As mentioned in the question I already tried to set the spacing and gapping to 0. Set them to minus number does not help either. In the end I just got the screen width and divided them by 4 and used that as the imageView width(I have 4 images in a row as requirement) and it appears working. I said appears because it looks to me the image views overlap a little bit when pressed on one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I just calculated the screen width and divided it by the number of columns, and use the result as the width for one item. I want in a row. That fixed the problem. The answer by mmmmm5 perhaps is correct that the gap is the padding added by android, we just need to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Android's source code for Contacts, a custom GridView class is created. Reviewing quickly, there are settings to paddings, etc. Perhaps, that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

There is another working solution. When returning the view from the `getView()` method in the adapter for the `GridView`, you have to set layout parameters as follows:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the padding isn't added in your adapter, look at your XML.  Look at android:stretchMode as well as android:verticalSpacing and android:horizontalSpacing.

```
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="14dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler, in the xml of my cell, I put the following parameters on the root view

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and setup my gridview like that:

```
   <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="3"
    tools:listitem="@layout/cell_type"
    />
```